# Using printf / scanf in X64 MASM

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, printf, x86-64, masm

This MASM X64 comes out of a textbook. I can't get it to compile in Visual Studio. I have written and compiled MASM X32 programs with `printf` / `scanf` successfully with Visual Studio. I cannot tell if I am calling `printf` / `scanf` wrong with X64 or am having MASM compile error issues. It gives me an "unresolved external symbol" error for `printf` and `scanf`. Any insight would help.

```
; Section 11.9 Complete Program


printf    PROTO     
scanf     PROTO  
        .data
msg1fmt   byte "%s",0
msg2fmt   byte 0Ah,"%s",0Ah,0Ah,0
msg3fmt   byte "   %lld", 0Ah,0Ah,0
in1fmt    byte "%lld",0
msg2      byte "Enter an integer: ",0
msg3      byte "Reversed",0
n         sqword 5
arry      sqword 5 dup(?)
        .code
main      proc
        mov rcx,n                     ; initialize rcx to n
        mov rbx,0                     ; initialize rbx to 0
for01:    nop
        push rcx                      ; save rcx
        lea rcx, msg1fmt
        lea rdx, msg2
        sub rsp, 40
        CALL printf
        add rsp, 40
        lea rcx, in1fmt
        lea rdx,arry[rbx]
        sub rsp,40
        call scanf
        add rsp,40
        pop rcx                       ; restore rcx
        add rbx,8                     ; increment rbx by 8
        loop for01
endfor01: nop

        lea rcx, msg2fmt
        lea rdx, msg3
        sub rsp, 40
        CALL printf
        add rsp, 40
        mov rcx,n                     ; initialize rcx to n
        sub rbx,8                     ; subtract 8 from rbx

for02:    nop
        push rcx                      ; save rcx
        lea rcx, msg3fmt
        mov rdx, arry[rbx]
        sub rsp, 40
        CALL printf
        add rsp, 40
        pop rcx                       ; restore rcx
        sub rbx,8                     ; decrement rbx by 8
        loop for02
endfor02: nop

        ret
main      endp
        end
```

Comment: Don't you need `includelib <msvcrt.lib>` and `extern printf: proc`?  How are you assembling and linking this?

Comment: So I would have to   include the following

includelib      msvcrtd
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.
includelib libcmt.lib
includelib libvcruntime.lib
    extern scanf: PROC
    extern printf: PROC
    extern exit: PROC

Comment: I'm not sure all of those libraries are required.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Try adding an `_` to the function name. Instead of calling `printf`, call `_printf`. And try the same also for scanf (`_scanf`)

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `scanf` are part of the C runtime library `libcmt.lib` and
you'll need the keyword `extern` to declare them as external procedures.

**reverse.asm**

```
option casemap:none

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib user32.lib
includelib libcmt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

extern printf:proc
extern scanf:proc


; Section 11.9 Complete Program


        .data
msg1fmt   byte "%s",0
msg2fmt   byte 0Ah,"%s",0Ah,0Ah,0
msg3fmt   byte "   %lld", 0Ah,0Ah,0
in1fmt    byte "%lld",0
msg2      byte "Enter an integer: ",0
msg3      byte "Reversed",0
n         sqword 5
arry      sqword 5 dup(?)
        .code
main      proc
        mov rcx,n                     ; initialize rcx to n
        mov rbx,0                     ; initialize rbx to 0
for01:    nop
        push rcx                      ; save rcx
        lea rcx, msg1fmt
        lea rdx, msg2
        sub rsp, 40
        CALL printf
        add rsp, 40
        lea rcx, in1fmt
        lea rdx,arry[rbx]
        sub rsp,40
        call scanf
        add rsp,40
        pop rcx                       ; restore rcx
        add rbx,8                     ; increment rbx by 8
        loop for01
endfor01: nop

        lea rcx, msg2fmt
        lea rdx, msg3
        sub rsp, 40
        CALL printf
        add rsp, 40
        mov rcx,n                     ; initialize rcx to n
        sub rbx,8                     ; subtract 8 from rbx

for02:    nop
        push rcx                      ; save rcx
        lea rcx, msg3fmt
        mov rdx, arry[rbx]
        sub rsp, 40
        CALL printf
        add rsp, 40
        pop rcx                       ; restore rcx
        sub rbx,8                     ; decrement rbx by 8
        loop for02
endfor02: nop

        ret
main      endp
        end
```

The above was compiled and linked using these commands:

```
@echo on

if not defined DevEnvDir (
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
)

ml64.exe /c reverse.asm

link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:console /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO reverse.obj
```

Running the program outputs

[image: out]

Comment: Doesn't this misalign the stack?  One `push rcx` and `sub rsp, 40` is an even multiple of 8 total change to RSP.  Should be `sub rsp, 32`.  (And `add rsp, 32` after, but really you should just `sub rsp,32` at the top of the function and undo it once before `ret`, not inside the loop.  Use a call-preserved reg for your loop counter, or don't use push/pop for it.)

Comment: This also violates the calling convention by modifying the caller's RBX.  You should `push rbx` / `push rdi` or something to start the function, then `sub rsp, 40`, and use RBX and RDI as your loop variables.  They're call-preserved in Windows x64 so they'll survive across function calls.  Obviously don't use the slow `loop` instruction, use `dec ebx` / `jnz`.